# Evaluate a certain volume integral

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $\iiint_B zdV $where B is bounded above by the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 17$ and below by $z = 1$

What I have done: By converting to cylindrical coordinates, I find that $ z = \sqrt{17 - r^2}$. When mapping to 2D, I find that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 17$ where z = 1 $\rightarrow x^2 + y^2 = 16 \rightarrow r = 4$

In total, my limits of integration are as follow $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{4} \int_{1}^{\sqrt{17 - r^2}} z dz r dr d\theta$

Comment: Looks good. What's the question?

Comment: are the limits of integration correct?

Comment: Yes, they are correct. Alternatively, you can do $\iiint_Bz=\int_1^\sqrt{17}z\iint_{x^2+y^2\le 17-z^2}...dxdy\,dz$ and change to the polar coordinates in $x,y$ (or notice that the inner integral is just the disc area $\pi(17-z^2)$).